# C++ to Java interface

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I am implementing a C++ to Java interface using JNI. I have a C++ function as follows:

`static int testhandler(void *arg, uint32_t stream, uint32_t func, const char* name, uint32_t funcgroup, uint32_t source);`

When I have to call this in Java using eclipse, I do it as follows:

`public void handle(int stream, int func,char name, int group, int token);`

But I am not able to read the const char part in Java using Eclipse. Does anybody know what the problem might be? Should I call the method in Java in some other manner?

Comment: In Java, `char` is a UTF-16 encoded character. In C++, `char` is a byte, and `char *` is most likely a nul-terminated string.

Comment: Loot at http://electrofriends.com/qna/jni-faq/convert-jstring-cstyle-string-vice-versa/. It should help.

Comment: At least testhandler doesn't look like a JNI function. Did you miss something we should know?

Comment: @Angew I use a Java function signature from C++ to Java as follows: "(IICII)V" Should I change the C to B(Byte) or String? I am not sure how to set signature for string though.

Comment: @BlueWanderer the JNI part is like this:JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_otf_OtfJni_otfjni_1set_1handler
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint type, jobject handler)
{
 struct callback *cb;
 jclass handler_class = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, handler);

 cb = (struct callback *)malloc(sizeof(struct callback));

 cb->env = env;
 cb->handler = (*env)->NewGlobalRef(env, handler);
 cb->id = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, handler_class, "handle", "(IICII)V");

 printf("adding a handler\n");
 OTF_HandlerArray_setHandler(handlers, testhandler, type);
 OTF_HandlerArray_setFirstHandlerArg(handlers, (void *)cb, type);

Comment: Im sorry but I dont know how to include the code part here..Im new here :(

Comment: You can edit your post. So basically you pass the function pointer to Java, but how you call the function pointer?

Comment: @BlueWanderer the function is called in java using      public void handle(int stream, int func, char name, int group, int token);     Is this what you meant to ask me?

Comment: I wanted to ask you to post the implementation of JNI function that handles the call and it's Java counter part.

Comment: @BlueWanderer The JNIExport function makes a call to testhandler which has the const char*. The JNI code is something like this: 
`JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_otf_OtfJni_otfjni_1set_1handler (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint type, jobject handler){ 

OTF_HandlerArray_setHandler(handlers, testhandler, type);

 }`
And the testhandler function is: 

`{
struct callback *cb = (struct callback *)arg; 

JNIEnv *env = cb->env; 

(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, cb->handler, cb->id, stream, func, name, funcgroup, source); 

return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, name);
}`

Comment: And the Java part is like this:
`public interface IOtfHandler {

 public void handle(long time, int state, int cpuid, int token);
 public void handle(int stream, int func, String name, int group, int token);
 
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just pass `const char*` string through JNI.

Create a `jstring` from it using function `NewStringUTF` (it is member-function of class `JNIEnv`). Then pass it to Java's `String`.

Comment: I understand that I have to use **NewStringUTF**, but in my case, the *const char** is part of a function call as seen in testhandler. So shud I use the **NewStringUTF** inside the function call or inside the JNIExport function?

Comment: @user2358330 Could you please give some code parts here for me to understand what do you mean?

Comment: The JNIExport function makes a call to testhandler which has the const char*. The JNI code is something like this: 
`JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_otf_OtfJni_otfjni_1set_1handler (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jint type, jobject handler){ 
OTF_HandlerArray_setHandler(handlers, testhandler, type);
 }`
And the testhandler function is: 
`{
struct callback *cb = (struct callback *)arg; 
JNIEnv *env = cb->env; 
(*env)->CallVoidMethod(env, cb->handler, cb->id, stream, func, name, funcgroup, source); 
return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, name);
}`

Comment: @user2358330 I can't get the logic. Why `int testhandler` is returning `jstring`?
When I was answering the main question, I meant that parameter `name` of type `char` in java is not equivalent to `const char*` from C++. Here you need `NewStringUTF` to convert this parameter to `jstring` and give to java function, which gets `String`.

Comment: @user2358330 I thought of something like this: `env->CallVoidMethod(......., env->NewStringUTF(name), .....)`.

Comment: I have changed the program now. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939349/convert-char-to-jstring-in-jni-when-char-is-passed-using-va-arg and let me know if you have any answers for that. Thanks in advance!